# keyof array type in TS is strange

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
interface PPP {
  1: number
  2: string
  4: boolean
}

type Map1<T extends any[]> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends keyof PPP ? PPP[T[K]] : never}
type Map2<T extends any[], U extends keyof T> = {[K in U]: T[K] extends keyof PPP ? PPP[T[K]] : never}

type Y1 = Map1<[1, 2]> // type Y1 = [number, string]
type Y2 = Map2<[1, 2], keyof [1, 2]> // type Y2 is not same as Y1
// type Y2 = {
//     [x: number]: string | number;
//     0: number;
//     1: string;
//     length: string;
//     toString: never;
//     toLocaleString: never;
//     pop: never;
//     push: never;
//     concat: never;
//     join: never;
//     reverse: never;
//     shift: never;
//     slice: never;
//     sort: never;
//     ... 20 more ...;
//     flat: never;
// }
```

As I know about TS, I would think Map1 is equivalent to Map2, however Y1 is not same as Y2, so there must be something that I don't know.

Question: what is the reason that causes this difference.

Comment: Because the type is an array that can only contain the values 1,2,4. The type key of iterates over is array, it does not care what it can contain as values.

Comment: @pascalpuetz I updated my description, with your comment, I still can not figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript runs the type checking at build time, not runtime.
Consider the following:

```
const a: (1 | 2 | 4)[] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
const b: (1 | 2 | 4)[] = [1, 2, 4]
```

Both `a` and `b` are valid (since they are arrays that contain items that are either `1`, `2` or `4`.

`keyof T` on typescript lists all the properties of the type `T`. For an array, you can also run `array.toString()` or `array.push()`. Hence, `toString` and `push` appears as valid times.

Typescript will never be able to list, at compile time, the items on the array as your type.

---

### Update

Indeed, there is a bug on typescript regarding the different behaviour between `keyof T` coming from type argument to the `keyof T` in the type value.
[Bug link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995)

You can, though, bypass this issue with an `Exclude`

[Link for the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAruQbwFDOQRgC5kQBXAWwCNpdkAmYgZzClAHNaAWYyge14A2EOCGwBfbNjABPAA4oAsnFn4APABVkEAB6QQAE0bIR0gNoBdAHzIAvFlMBpZKGQBrCNN4xk688XWO5lq6EAZG7p7e6KjIAPxo6KYBDuZBxCAQAG7QEjLyyEqydBrBeobGIGbmADTIAKqloeURXj7WdpiOziD1fj6BjWFuHq3RcQmoSYFpJFk5knmKygDMJTplRiYWtQ3rTeEj3urt9k4uAKLaCAKk%20hCqdbUt3ltWfclBe0PPE%20PRUykZhlslAJJIFnIUABNfC2ArKNSmfC1OhWZAAenRyEWyBhcNMZCo0FqzFYIDY5ikkNxdDhhWKSJRNWGkWQjPoaMx2OpUNpwCMIF4YGQjDg5BQcCMMKp%20ShyzpK1U7NRT0ObORHMs2CAA)

```js
interface PPP {
  1: number
  2: string
  4: boolean
}

type Map1 < T extends any[] > = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends keyof PPP ? PPP[T[K]] : never
}
type Map2 < T extends any[], U extends keyof T > = {
  [K in U]: T[K] extends keyof PPP ? PPP[T[K]] : never
}

type Map3 < T extends any[], U extends keyof T > = {
  [K in Exclude < U, keyof any[] > ]: T[K] extends keyof PPP ? PPP[T[K]] : never
}




type Y1 = Map1 < [1, 2] > // type Y1 = [number, string]
  type Y2 = Map2 < [1, 2], keyof[1, 2] > // type Y2 is not same as Y1
  type Y3 = Map3 < [1, 2], keyof[1, 2] > // Same as Y3
```